# Hiding/Showing text in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working to develop a mobile application using Xamarin Forms.  I would like to make certain text appear when a button is pushed in the application, and otherwise be hidden.  However, I am not sure how to do this using XAML and C#.  I tried writing a conditional, with a Console.WriteLine() command, but the text does not show in the application.  Are there any suggestions on how to solve this problem, or what resources I should look into to learn more about this?

XAML Code - Buttons:

```
 <Button Text="I am new to this app" Clicked="Button_Clicked"> 
 </Button><Button Text="I have used this app before" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"></Button
```

C# Code for these buttons:

```
    /* This only changes the label of the buttons, it doesn't make the text appear separately like I want it to.*/

  void Button_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Text = "Hey there! Welcome to this awesome app!";

    }

    void Button_Clicked_1(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Text = "Welcome back!";

    }
```

Comment: use the `IsVisible` property of any UI element to show/hide it.  If you need further help, pleaes **post the relevant code** so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Hi!  Added the code now.  Thank you for your suggestion and your answer.

Comment: I still have no idea what you want to do.  There are two buttons - when the user clicks them what should happen?  Do you want one button to hide when the other one is clicked?

Comment: Hi! When one button is clicked, I would like text to appear below the button (certain text for one button, different text for the other).  I hope that this clears your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Labels` to display the additional text

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Text="I am new to this app" Clicked="Button_Clicked" /> 
<Label x:Name="Label1" Text="Hey there! Welcome to this awesome app!" IsVisible="False" />
<Button x:Name="Button2" Text="I have used this app before" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
<Label x:Name="Label2" Text="Welcome back!" IsVisible="False" />
```

then in the code behind you can change the `IsVisible` property of each label

```
void Button_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.IsVisible = true;
}

void Button_Clicked_1(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.IsVisible = true;
}
```